# If statement is not giving the correct answer ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I currently am trying to find the error in my if/else statement I ran some small test to see if my variables are holding values, which they are but I keep getting zero when I click on the submit button.

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pack_Weight.TextChanged

End Sub

Protected Sub Submit_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit_Button.Click
    Dim PackageW, MemphisRate, SanFranRate As Double

    'takes user input from the textbox and places it in the variable
    PackageW = Pack_Weight.Text

    'if user selects the dropbox and radiobutton list the selected combo should charge a varying bag fee
    If Location.SelectedValue = "1" & ShippingList.SelectedValue = "1" Then
        MemphisRate = 2.2 * PackageW

    ElseIf Location.SelectedValue = "1" & ShippingList.SelectedValue = "2" Then
        MemphisRate = 2.59 * PackageW

    ElseIf Location.SelectedValue = "1" & ShippingList.SelectedValue = "3" Then
        MemphisRate = 2.92 * PackageW

    End If
    'outputs the user selected combo to the total amount textbox
    Total_Cost.Text = MemphisRate

    If Location.SelectedValue = "2" & ShippingList.SelectedValue = "1" Then
        SanFranRate = 2.2 * PackageW

    ElseIf Location.SelectedValue = "2" & ShippingList.SelectedValue = "2" Then
        SanFranRate = 2.59 * PackageW

    ElseIf Location.SelectedValue = "2" & ShippingList.SelectedValue = "3" Then
        SanFranRate = 2.92 * PackageW

    End If

    Total_Cost.Text = SanFranRate

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which is giving you 0? Always parse/convert the received input to numeric type before performing any calculations on them.

Comment: that is when what I currently testing to try and figure out because everything is giving zero at the moment and I can't figure out where in the if statement could it be getting zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform input validation before trying to process the input.

Using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) will make sure that all data types match up, e.g. it will stop you from trying to assign a string to a numeric variable.

When you're calculating monetary values, it is better to use the Decimal type instead of Double.

There are a lot of `If... ElseIf`s in there - it would look a bit tidier to use [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx), like this:

```
Option Strict On
' ...

Protected Sub Submit_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit_Button.Click
    Dim packageW As Decimal

    ' INPUT VALIDATION
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(Pack_Weight.Text, packageW) Then
        ' inform user that a number is required
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Location.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        ' inform user that a location must be selected
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ShippingList.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        ' inform user that a shipping type must be selected
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' CALCULATE SHIPPING COST
    Dim shippingRate As Decimal = 0D

    Select Case Location.SelectedItem.Text
        Case "1" ' Memphis
            Select Case ShippingList.SelectedItem.Text
                Case "1" ' Economy
                    shippingRate = 2.2D
                Case "2" ' Normal
                    shippingRate = 2.59D
                Case "3" ' Speedy
                    shippingRate = 2.92D
            End Select

        Case "2" ' San Francisco
            Select Case ShippingList.SelectedItem.Text
                Case "1"
                    shippingRate = 2.2D
                Case "2"
                    shippingRate = 2.59D
                Case "3"
                    shippingRate = 2.92D
            End Select

    End Select

    Dim shippingCost As Decimal = Math.Round(packageW * shippingRate, 2)
    Total_Cost.Text = shippingRate.ToString()

End Sub
```

I find `.SelectedItem.Text` to be more reliable than `.SelectedValue`.

It was not clear to me what good names for some of the variables would be - you should change them to make sense.

It was not quite clear from the comments in the code if a state of no selections is valid - if so, take out the checks for `.SelectedIndex = 1`. You might want to make sure the user has entered a valid `packageW`, i.e. not negative and not unreasonably large.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `&` incorrectly.  In VB.NET, the `&` operator is for string concatenation.  You should be using the keyword `And` or `AndAlso` instead.

Comment: thank you but I changed all of the &'s to And's and it still is not going through the if statement correctly.